# Rails RESTful routs without #new, rspec trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm currently writing a Rails app, and hit a somewhat strange quirk. I have a controller `PermissionsController`, which is mainly for display purposes at the moment. So my routing is locked down:

```
map.resources :permissions, :only => [:index, :show]
```

Unfortunately, when writing the tests, one of the routing tests fails:

```
it "does not recognize #new" do
  { :get => "/permissions/new" }.should_not be_routable
end
```

with the error:

```
Expected 'GET /permissions/new' to fail, but it routed to
{"action"=>"show", "id"=>"new", "controller"=>"permissions"} instead
```

Obviously, the #show action's route is matching with `/permissions/:id`, which also gives the expected error `Couldn't find Permission with ID=new` if you actually browse to that URL.

This is not a serious error, as it is correctly raising an exception with the bad :id parameter, but it's kind of ugly. Is there any way to actually make Rails reject that route? Some trick in the routing options that I'm missing?

I suppose I should just leave that test out and ignore it, or maybe remove the whole RESTful idea altogether and go back to a simpler `map.connect 'permissions/:id'` style. I strongly suspect I'll be expanding this in the future, though, and kind of wanted to keep my controllers consistent with each other. Just having to add occasional :only or :except rules made routes.rb nice and clean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is mapping correctly as you point out. If you want to ensure that `:id` is always a number then you would not have this problem.

This can be done with a requirement on the route.

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id', :requirements => { :id => /\d?/ }
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format', :requirements => { :id => /\d?/ }
```